# What is the *iterator for a map<int,int>? It's not pair<int,int>

Tags: c++, dictionary, find

I'm testing the STL find algorithm. And I reached the maps containers. However, map has its own method (map_name.find(key)). Even so, the generic find function should work, if a pair is provided as element to find. But it doesn't work.

I tried finding a pair of the elements in the map, but it doesn't work. I tried finding a *iterator and it works. So... that means *iterator is not a pair?!

```
map<int,int> m = {{0,1}, {1,2}, {2,3}};
map<int,int>::iterator it;
pair<int,int> p = make_pair(0,1);
//this returns compilation error
//it = find(m.begin(), m.end(), p);
//this works fine
it = find(m.begin(), m.end(), *m.begin());
cout << it->first << ' ' << it->second << endl; //prints 0 1
```

I would have expected 0 1 in both cases, but it seems that the deferenced map::iterator it is not a pair. Than what is it?

Comment: What is the compilation error? And have you tried looking at suitable [reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to check what map's `value_type` is?

Comment: `map<<int,int>::iterator it;` remove one of those `<`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. The *iterator it's

```
pair<const int, int>
```

and not

```
par<int,int>
```

because the key element must be const in the map. Now it works.

Comment: I'm sorry for troubleing the ones that help. I see my question has 3 downvotes and I don't know why. It was my first question and a legitimate issue, as I saw it, but obviously it bothered some. This downvote with no reasons made me feel bullied... I wish it could be more friendly... Sorry if this is off topic. Hopefully, this comment will be useful in the future...